# weird green/yellow background when sorting using jquery ui-sortable

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I encountered a very weird bug where when I try to click and drag to sort elements, there is this green/yellow background behind it.  You can see the screenshot here: http://d.pr/8xNa.  Looking at it via Firebug, I don't see anything that could've created that background.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  li you are dragging is replaced with one li with class ui-state-highlight class.

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });
```

remove this placeholder from your code you are fine.